# Is there a defined protocol for reverse HTTP over WebSockets?

Tags: websocket

I'm a bit surprised I can't find anything coherent on this subject.

Say there is a duplex web-service protocol between two actors, say `A` and `B`, where duplex means that both of the actors expose some web service(s) that the other actor can call. None of the actors is a browser, i.e. the code on both has full control over the data it exchanges over `HTTP`.

Say it's possible that one of the actors (`A`) is deployed behind a device that prevents the other actor (`B`) to initiate any network connections to the former. Actor `A` can still make HTTP requests to `B`.

To overcome the network restrictions, let's add an endpoint that would support websocket connections, have `A` establish connection to `B`, and use that connection to receive HTTP requests `B` would normally send, replying with appropriate HTTP responses. HTTP protocol is so well formatted that can be exchanged in raw without much additional encapsulation.

[RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), however, highly suggests that the application protocol used inside websockets is properly negotiated using `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` (and it's called a sub-protocol). The well known protocols are [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml).

However, I can't find any registered sub-protocols that specify the use of reverse HTTP. Is it really not that common to use raw `HTTP` protocol inside web sockets, and instead fall back to some other (custom) standard? The reason I want to see `HTTP` being trafficked inside a websocket, is because I already have a web-service standard for the actor that may have to resort to using websockets, and I don't want to specify that operations twice.

Comment: Two things: 1. It seems to me that this use case wouldn't be as common as you think... Http/2 is already taking over Http with a persistent connection. Having said that, there's a project called `turbolinks` that I think is being (or was) ported to websockets from Ajax.

Comment: 2. Why not leverage the code for the Http API so that you can use it also in the websockets API? - You don't need to redo the whole Http section, just wrap the response in JSON or XML or move part of the code to an external method. I wrote an example for the [Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io/docs/basics#our-first-http-websocket-api) and I'm quire certain you could do it with whatever you're using.